# Jquery Text editor issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, text-editor, jqte

The following the code of the page where I want to use Jquery Text Editor (jqte). However, after much trying nothing seems to be working. I have included the required files in the same folder as the aspx page.The Jquery reference is included on the masterpage.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ArticleView.aspx.cs" Inherits="Articles_ArticleView" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
    <link href="jquery-te-1.3.6.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="jquery-te-1.3.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <div></div>

    <div>
        <textarea class="jqte-test" name="textarea"></textarea>
        <div name="div" class="jqte-test"></div>
    </div>

    <div></div>

    <script>
        $('.jqte-test').jqte();
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: I said in the question the reference is included on MasterPage.

Comment: did you check error console in firebug?

Comment: @MohitArora Arora the following error is show in the console.   Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'jqte'

Comment: Have you included jQuery library? Try run your code inside document.ready function

Comment: Yes I have inclued the Jquery library

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/R4qEw/ check your dependencies and what jQuery version are you using?

Comment: That is why I am panicking because it seems okay. but does not work on my side.

Comment: Do you see any error (404) in browser network console? e.g. exists the file jquery-te-1.3.6.min.js in the same path of the page?

Comment: actually they are all 200 (OK)..

Comment: But the error Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'jqte' is a typical resource missing error, strange; can you post other infos?

Comment: let us say reference 1 `<link href="/ProfileTenModified/JQuery-TE_v.1.3.6/jquery-te-1.3.6.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />` reference 2 
    `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>` reference 3 
   `<script src="/ProfileTenModified/JQuery-TE_v.1.3.6/jquery-te-1.3.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` they are all inside the application ProfileTemModified and they are all loading correctly.

Comment: Are you including jQuery twice? From the masterPage and the child? If so, remove the reference from the child page

Comment: No that is not helping either.. seems like a bad day for me..

Comment: @Edward okay dear as I told unclucky day.. they clock changed to 1:00 am and it started to work without any reason..

Comment: Mysterious day! Happy you have "solved" :-)