# JQTE Jquery text editor issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, richtextbox, jqte

I want to run the jQuery Text Editor on the following aspx page. but I tried for hours with any success. Getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'jqte'`. I have included all the required libraries. The MasterPage has the reference to the jquery library. There are no visible errors.

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master"  AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ArticleView.aspx.cs" Inherits="Articles_ArticleView" %>

    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
    <link href="../JQuery-TE_v.1.3.6/jquery-te-1.3.6.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="/ProfileTenModified/JQuery-TE_v.1.3.6/jquery-te-1.3.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    </asp:Content>
    <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#jqte-test').jqte();
    });

   </script>

   <textarea id="jqte-test" name="textarea" ></textarea>
   <div name="div" class="jqte-test"></div>

   </asp:Content>
```

Comment: You have already asked the same question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16624548/jquery-text-editor-issue

Comment: So??? any solutions? I thought to let you people notice again... I am desperate..

Comment: So don't ask same question; be patient someone will help you